# Ubuntu 18.04 is accepting cron job

Tags: 18.04, cron

I am trying to set a cron job in ubuntu18.04 but it is giving me error of command not found

```
root@UB-Machine:~# * * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
Machine: command not found
```

I have tried restarting cron but still i am getting same error

Answer (score 2):

Run `crontab -e` to edit your current `crontab`.

Add the entry there. Save and exit the editor.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/env > /tmp/env.output
```

This will run the command every minute.